# Mapping Luis Entities to Dialog Fields

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm having trouble getting my Luis Entities to bind to my FormFlow fields so I can skip steps in the FormFlow. A simplified version of my FormFlow dialog is as follows

```
[Serializable]
public class DoSearch
{
    public string SearchTerm;

    public static IForm<DoSearch> BuildForm()
    {
        var builder = new FormBuilder<DoSearch>();

        return builder
            .Message("Search Function")
            .Field(nameof(DoSearch.SearchTerm))
            .AddRemainingFields()
            .Confirm("Are you sure you wish to search for {SearchTerm} ?")
            .Build();
    }

}
```

And I am calling this with the following code

```
    public async Task StartSearch(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {

        var searchForm = new BuildForm<DoSearch>(() => DoSearch.BuildForm());
        var searchForm1 = new FormDialog<DoSearch>(new DoSearch(), searchForm , FormOptions.PromptInStart, result.Entities);
        context.Call<searchForm>(searchForm1, SearchComplete);
        // ...
    }
```

The result.Entities does contain the appropriate entity (Type = SearchTerm) but the FormFlow always asks for this when it runs.

The example Pizza bot sample code seems to work, but I can't seem to get it to bind the entity to the field.

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Ian_Boggs, could you perhaps share your source on how you mixed LuisDialog with FormFlow in the first place? I'm trying to do the same but have yet to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a bug. Entities seem to bind to properties that are Enums, but that are strings.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/151

Hopefully this will be sorted at some point

Answer (score 0):

If you get the last version of the SDK it should work.

This has been fixed in this commit : https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/commit/e81b9dd23b3c69024caf8b53dcddc0bf158f61e2