# Connecting LUIS dialog to form dialog and mapping builtin fields

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a similar issue to this: [Connecting LUIS dialog to form dialog and mapping the right fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998505/connecting-luis-dialog-to-form-dialog-and-mapping-the-right-fields)

Except I am using built in entities in LUIS such as builtin.number, which I have given a name in LUIS e.g. Amount, but the mapping seems to only be between the field type in the form class and the entity type in the LUIS JSON. Obviously I can't have a field named builtin.number.

How would I go about mapping built in LUIS entities with a form field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to create a new EntityRecommendation in your LuisIntent method using the Type that will map against your form class. Then you can add that entity into the list of entities you will pass to your form.

```
// not checking if entity exists for simplicity
var builtInEntity = result.Entities.First(x => x.Type == "builtin.number");

var entity = new EntityRecommendation();
entity.Type = "Amount";
entity.Entity = builtInEntity.Entity;

result.Entities.Add(entity);
```